# Proof of Schiffler Point using affine geometry?

Tags: geometry, analytic-geometry, affine-geometry

**Theorem:** ***A triangle ABC with the incenter I has its Schiffler point at the point of concurrence of the Euler lines of the four triangles BCI, CAI, ABI, and ABC. Schiffler's theorem states that these four lines all meet at a single point.***

**The statement of the theorem** :
**Question** : I want to find a demonstration and process this result without using the idea of circle or perpendicularity. I have been trying for a few days to find a similar demonstration of this result, possibly using barycentric calculus. I only managed to discover some results that could take out the idea of ​​bisectors and replaced the bisector with reports (**Angle bisector theorem**) and a result that describes the line of Euler with the help of parallels. Specifically, I really want to prove this result using only concepts of parallelism and segment reports.

***Help theorem*** : *Let P be any point int he plane whatsoever. Let $L_A$ be the line through the vertex A that is parallel to the line through PP and the midpoint A′ of the opposite side BC. Let the lines $L_B$ and $L_C$ be constructed similarly. Then, the three line LA, LB and LC have a point Q in common, the points G,P and Q lie on the line, and $GQ=2PG$.* The more accurate question is: **How can I prove the result of the 'theorem' Schiffler Point with the help of the theorem mentioned above or using other results, but only using the concept of parallelism and ratios (exactly in the affine space)?**

Comment: "Help me please" is not to be used, especially in a title...

Comment: Have you made a Google search of relevant topics ? Do you accept to use trilinear coordinates like in (https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SchifflerPoint.html) ?

Comment: I also tried this variant, but it also consists in using the concept of angle. Which is not exactly specific in affine geometry.

Comment: And the point of the inscribed circle is the intersection of the bisectors. Which also represents a concept that is not found in an affine geometry.

Comment: Maybe, you have first to consider an "Affine generalization of the Euler line" which is precisely the title of [this Article](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2320469?seq=1) in American Mathematical Monthly.

Comment: From this chapter I took the theorem I presented above, which I called the "Help Theorem". But I don't know exactly how I could use it. I understood the description, I understood how it works, but I don't know how I can use it in my theorem.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/107877/discussion-between-andvld-and-jean-marie).